# How can I get paragraphs to scale with font size within CSS flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This should most probably be an easy thing to do, I've been trying for hours now however which got my level of frustration high enough to finally register on StackOverflow. Google offers plenty of related questions and examples, but I've been unable to find anything regarding my specific problem.

I'm trying to create a div that will contain a (horizontally and vertically centered) column of paragraphs. These paragraphs should scale with their respective font sizes, which they don't.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid red; display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; align-items: center; width: 500px; height: 250px;">
  <p style="border: 1px solid blue; font-size: 6rem;">The Header</p>
  <p style="border: 1px solid blue; font-size: 1rem;">Some Text</p>
</div>
```

[Screenshot (I don't have the permissions to directly post images yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaZdy.png)

I have tried multiple things, but the paragraphs are only adjusting their height according to the font size when using `display:block` in the parent div and `display:inline` for the paragraphs. Since I want to use flexbox for centering this is not an option however.

So my questions are:

- Why are the paragraphs within the div not adjusting their height to the text?
- How do I get them to properly (vertically) adjust and avoid overlapping of text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% clear what end result you want but it seems your code is fine but you hadn't  removed the default margin applied by browsers to p tags.

```css
.wrap {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
}

.wrap p {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap .p1 {
  font-size: 6rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <p class="p1">The Header</p>
  <p>Some Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it has shown me that the code works fine in other environments, just not in mine. To be more specific, I'm using it as an Angular Component. My Angular application uses Angular Material, I have now found out that ```<body class="mat-typography">``` for some reason causes the behavior shown in the Screenshot. I would upvote your answer if I could but since I'm new here my reputation score isn't high enough.